# Intentionally throttle 3rd party javascript file from cdn

Tags: javascript, networking, cdn

The question:

How can we intentionally throttle a 3rd party javascript file loaded from a cdn in order to reproduce behavior exhibited by a customer?

The situation:

In our app, we received a report from a customer that part of our page loaded quickly and another part loaded slowly. After getting on a screenshare with them, we determined that a 3rd party library (PushWooosh) loaded over a cdn was taking a long time to load and would eventually fail.

What appears to be happening is that the customer is accessing our site on a restricted network that is blocking the 3rd party library. This particular library is not critical to the app but is included in such a way that the rest of the javascript on the site is blocking until this library loads. The customer's network is configured in such a way that it takes 30s-1m for the file to eventually fail loading causing portions of our site to not finish loading until this failure takes place.

What I'd like to do is intentionally throttle the Pushwoosh library from our network, so it takes a long time to load so that we can code a fix and know that it will work for the customer.

I know that Chrome can simulate low bandwidth connections, but I don't see a way to do this on a per-file basis.

Are there any other ways to simulate/throttle network connections on a per file basis?

Comment: There are network appliances designed to do just that.

Comment: I am pretty sure the Chrome dev tools only allow you to slow down the entire connection. Could you potentially remove the CDN call to PushWoosh and then try to dynamically load it in the window.onload event to at least delay the loading?

Comment: @matt yes that is likely the solution or something similar, but we want to test if that will solve it and not introduce other things.